# findBy() and findAll() produce empty curly bracket

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony2 and doctrine_mongodb. Please why does my findBy and findAll produce empty curly brackets? user_id is integer.

```
    $repository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getRepository('MyMpBundle:Scripts');
```

And I have tried the following:

```
$scripts = $repository -> findBy(array('user_id' => 1)); //produces empty {}
$scripts = $repository -> findAll(); //produces empty{}
$scripts = $repository -> findOneBy(array('user_id' => 1)); //produces value
```

I wish to assign $scripts to all documents in the mongodb database.
The Scripts.php is shown below:

```
 /**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */

class scripts
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
public $name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
public $description;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Int
 */
public $index;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Int
 */
public $user_id;
```

Any Help pls :)

Comment: Can you show how the `$repository` value is obtained? And, add anything else you might think is relevant to the problem?

Comment: thanks. I have edited the question with the repository and Scripts.php.

Comment: How are you inspecting the value of `$scripts`?  Your examples that produce "empty" results both return a [Cursor](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.Cursor.html) object rather than a document, while your example that works returns a single document. In the first two cases I suspect you need to iterate the returned cursor (with `foreach` or `$scripts->getNext()`).

Comment: Nice help Stennie, I now get value for findBY and findAll using foreach but I only get the first document.                                   $scripts = $repository -> findAll();
foreach ($scripts as $value)
  {
  $response = new Response(json_encode($value));
 return $response;
  }

Comment: Thanks again Stennie. Works now.I needed to iterate the returned cursor.

Comment: @Stennie, want to post an answer so that Kingsley can accept it? That, or you can post/accept your own answer again Kingsley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @Stenie:

> How are you inspecting the value of $scripts? Your examples that produce "empty" results both return a Cursor object rather than a document, while your example that works returns a single document. In the first two cases I suspect you need to iterate the returned cursor (with foreach or $scripts->getNext()).